# Getting ad-users Manager DisplayName output

Tags: powershell

I want to fetch the manager's user object and grab the DisplayName instead of the DN.

```
$expiredaccounts = Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan 70.00:00:00 | Where-Object { ($_.Enabled -eq $true) }


$expiredaccounts | Select-Object name, SamAccountName, @{Name='EmployeeID';Expression={($_ |Get-ADUser -Properties employeeID).employeeID}} , @{Name='Manager';Expression={($_ |Get-ADUser -Properties manager).manager}}
```

Output :

```
name          SamAccountName    EmployeeID Manager                                                            
----          --------------    ---------- -------                                                            
User user01                                CN=User,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe it to `Get-ADUser` once again:

```
$expiredaccounts | Select-Object name, SamAccountName, @{Name='EmployeeID';Expression={($_ |Get-ADUser -Properties employeeID).employeeID}} , @{Name='Manager';Expression={ (($_ |Get-ADUser -Properties manager).manager | Get-ADUser).Name}}
```

---

**Explanation**:

You take the `Manager` property and run `Get-ADUser` against it. It returns user object of user's manager. Using `.Name` you extract the only required property, which is display name.